# How to call Purchase Order Number payment method in another place?

Tags: orders, magento-1.9.3.3

Can we call Purchase Order Number payment method display on one-page checkout above of "REVIEW YOUR ORDER" table?

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('purchase_order'); ?>
```

Comment: No, i m asking this only for Magento 1.9.3.3

Comment: Hello @Dhaduk Mitesh don't change my post here i m looking for Magento ver 1.9.3.3 okay

Comment: make it magento ver 1.9.3.3 now

Comment: Please write proper content in question. If your question not understand by anyone that how they give you answer. and how you get right solution for your answer. **@Ashish**

Comment: I know very well but this is the correct question if question About Magento 2 then mentions 1st in any question. anyway thanks, dear.